# Why doesn't Google index my AJAX fetched content?

Tags: ajax, reactjs

I have this website I've built using ReactJS and I'm trying to add a new page that fetchs data using AJAX in the componentDidMount method.

The page has some static components such as navbar and footer and it shows a loader until the data is fetched, but the weird thing is that when I submit the url to Fetch as Google, it shows a completely blank page.

It seems pretty weird to me as I expected that if Google doesn't wait for my AJAX call to return, it should have at least show me the navbar,footer and loader in the Fetch as Google result.

That's the code:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import axios from 'axios';
import CustomLoader from './CustomLoader';
import AppBar from './AppBar';

export default class GamePage extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={loading:true,description:''};
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get(`/someinternalAPI`).then((response)=>{
            this.setState({description:response.data,loading:false});
        });
    }

    render(){
        return(<div>
                    <AppBar />
                    {this.state.loading ? <CustomLoader /> : this.state.description}
                </div>);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up solving it by myself, just posting it in case someone else is having this issue(I'm sure some do).

What I did was checking if window.location.href matchs the page having this issue before calling ReactDOM.render, and if so, fetching the data and saving it and **then** calling ReactDOM.render.

I've also added a function to the page component that checks if the the data was already fetched, and if not, it fetchs it - that way the data is fetched before ReactDOM.render if the page is the first page to load on the site(which is how search engines crawlers access pages), or fetched dynamically via the page's componentWillMount function if the page is accessed after initial application load (which is how human users will mostly access it).

UPDATE: I've published a npm package that solves the issue. You can check it out here: https://github.com/DRYuval/react-seo .

Answer (score 0):

Simply Google's crawler doesn't parse dynamic content.

Good practice would be to make sure that your dynamic loaded content is also accessible on static link, so when you navigate to "yourwebsite.com/page1" it should show at least static text that's normally loaded with your axios, this way crawlers are aware of content on your website/application.

Further workaround would be to utilize server-side rendering which is SEO friendly and resolves problems like yours, as it prerenders all the content and website itself on a server-side and serves full website.

Comment: At one stage this may have been true but Google has parsed dynamic content for quite some time: https://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157